# Hadoop: wrong classpath in map reduce job

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, cloudera

I'm running a cloudera cluster in 3 virtual maschines and try to execute hbase bulk load via a map reduce job. But I got always the error:

```
error: Class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat not found
```

So, it seems that the map process doesnt find the class. So I tried this:

1) add the hbase.jar to the HADOOP_CLASSPATH on every node

2) adding TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(job) / TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(myConf, HFileOutputFormat.class) to my source code

nothing worked. I have absolute no idea why the class is not found, because the jar/class is definitely available in the classpath.

If I take a look into the job.xml I see the following entry:

```
name=tmpjars    value=file:/C:/Users/Thomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.5-cdh4.3.0/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.3.0.jar,file:/C:/Users/Thomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase/0.94.6-cdh4.3.0/hbase-0.94.6-cdh4.3.0.jar,file:/C:/Users/Thomas/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.0/hadoop-core-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.0.jar,file:/C:/Users/Thomas/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/11.0.2/guava-11.0.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/Thomas/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.4.0a/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar
```

This seems a little bit odd to me, these are my local jars on the windows system. Maybe this should be the hdfs jars? If yes, how can I change the values for "tmpjars"?

Here is the java code I try to execute:

```
        configuration = new Configuration(false);
        configuration.set("mapred.job.tracker", "192.168.2.41:8021");
        configuration.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://192.168.2.41:8020/");
        configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.2.41");
        configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");

        Job job = new Job(configuration, "HBase Bulk Import for "
                + tablename);
        job.setJarByClass(HBaseKVMapper.class);

        job.setMapperClass(HBaseKVMapper.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(KeyValue.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(HFileOutputFormat.class);
        job.setPartitionerClass(TotalOrderPartitioner.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad(job, hTable);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("myfile1"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("myfile2"));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);

        LoadIncrementalHFiles loader = new LoadIncrementalHFiles(
                configuration);
        loader.doBulkLoad(new Path("myFile3"), hTable);
```

EDIT:

I tried a little bit more and its totaly strange. I add the following line to the java code:

```
job.setJarByClass(HFileOutputFormat.class);
```

after I executed this, the error is gone, but another class not found exception appear:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class mypackage.bulkLoad.HBaseKVMapper not found
```

HBaseKVMapper is my custom Mapper Class I want to execute. So, I tried to add it with "job.setJarByClass(HBaseKVMapper.class)", but it doesnt work since its its only a class file and no jar. So I generated a Jarfile including HBaseKVMapper.class. After that, I executed it again and now got the HFileOutputFormat.class not found exception again.

After debugging a little bit, I found out that the setJarByClass Methode only copies the local jar file to .staging/job_#number/job.jar on HDFS. So, this setJarByClass() Method will only work for one jar file because it overwrites the job.jar after executing setJarByClass() again with another jar.

While searching for the eroor I saw the following strcuture in the the job staging direcotry:

[image: job staging direcotry]

and inside the libjars direcotry I saw the relevant jar files

[image: libjars directory]

so, the hbase jar is inside the libjars directory but the jobtracker doesn't use this it for executing the job. Why?

Comment: Try removing the line: `configuration.set("mapred.job.tracker", "192.168.2.41:8021");`

Comment: hey, tahnks for your answer. If i  remove the line the programm try to use the local jobtracker and there is no service running. My Setup: Node1+Node2+Node3 in a cloudera cluster and Windows1 as a client which connects to Node1

Comment: You must have Hadoop client setup in the machine from where you are running the Java program. Then basically, you need to use only the `configuration.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://192.168.2.41:8020/");` to specify that it's a dfs cluster.

Comment: "setup up haddop client" = creating core-site.xml/hbase-site.xml in the classpath? If yes, I did that before, but I got the same errors

Comment: If you remove the line I told, do you get any error?

Comment: Yes, I got errors. Like I said the programm try to use the local jobtracker, but there is obviously no tracker because its only the client node. I got this "error": cause:java.io.IOException: No valid local directories in property: mapred.local.dir

Answer (score 1):

I would try using Cloudera Manager (free version) as it takes care of these issues for you. Otherwise note the following:

Both your own classes and the HBase Class HFileOutputFormat need to be available on the classpath locally and remotely.

**Submitting the job**

Meaning getting the classpath right locally for when your driver runs:

```
$ env HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(hbase classpath) hadoop jar path/to/jar class....
```

**On the server**

In your hadoop-env.sh

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(hbase claspath)
```

or use

```
TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars
```

Comment: my comment was to long, see my answer above

Answer (score 0):

I found a "hacked" solution which worked for me, but I'm not happy with it because it's not really practicable.

My "hacked" solution:

1. create one big Jar with all necessary class files, I called it "big.jar" and add it to the local (eclipse) classpath
2. add the line: job.setJarByClass(MyMapperClass.class) ... the MyMapperClass has to be in the big.jar

When I execute this the big.jar will be copied for every job to the filesystem. No errors anymore. The problem is, that the jar is 80mb in size and have to be copied every time.

If anywone knows a better way I would be tahnkful if he could tell me how.

EDIT:

Now I try to execute jobs with Apache Pig and have exactly the same problem. My hacked soultion doesn't  work in this case because pig creats the jobs automaticly. Here is the pig error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableSplit not found
```